# Fixed content within scrollable column

Tags: html, scroll, bootstrap-4

I have two separately scrollable columns on my page. On the left column which has navigational role I  have two sub elements which are scrollable all together at the moment:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 theme-background left-panel nav-scroll">
      <p> a - this part I want to be fixed <p>
    <div>
      <p> b - this part is scrollable  </p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 nav-scroll">
      <p> c - scrollable as well<p>
    </div>   
 </div>
```

the general view is presented in the jfiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/macfol/wtx9zhsq/

What I would like to achieve is to have the bottom part (b) to be scrollable while having top part (a) to be fixed on top of the column and always visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to differentiate the scroll div with the fixed div
and keep the fixed div in `col-3`

[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtx9zhsq/4/)

please check the link

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav-scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 90vh;
  float:left;
  bottom: 0;
  top:0;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
}
.pLeftBar {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pFixed {
  height: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pScroll {
  height: 70%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 theme-background left-panel nav-scroll pLeftBar">
<div class="pFixed">
      <p>
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        
      </p>
</div>
    <div class="pScroll">
     <p>
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     </p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 nav-scroll">
     <p>
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     </p>
    </div>

    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```css
.head{
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow-y: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 20vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-scroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 90vh;
  float:left;
  margin 0 0 0 0;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 350px;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="head col-9" >  
 <p>
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        
      </p>
     <p>
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     </p>
    </div>
   
    <div class="col-9 nav-scroll">
     <p>
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     ccccccccccccc
     </p>
    </div>
 
 </body>
```